# Laravel query builder returning empty where phpmyadmin returns results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I am trying to resolve an issue where using Laravel's query builder I am getting no results, but when I run the same query in php my admin i got result's..

This is the query:

```
DB::table('nm_product')->select(
    DB::raw(
        'IF(LOCATE(" ",pro_title,POSITION("'.$products
        .'" IN pro_title))<>"0",SUBSTR(pro_title,POSITION("'.$products
        .'" IN pro_title),LOCATE(" ",pro_title,POSITION("'.$products
        .'" IN pro_title)) - POSITION("'.$products
        .'" IN pro_title) ) , "aaa")  as keyword'
    ),
    'mc_name',
    'pro_title'
)->join('nm_maincategory', 'mc_id', '=', 'pro_mc_id'
)->where(DB::raw('LOWER(pro_title)'),'like','"% '.$products.'%"'
)->orwhere(DB::raw('LOWER(pro_title)'),'like','"'.$products.'%"'
)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see what the query is running, it is a way of testing processes:

```
#Last Query
\DB::enableQueryLog();

// code request
DB::table('nm_product')->select(...

$query = \DB::getQueryLog();
$lastQuery = end($query);
\Log::info(json_encode($lastQuery));
```

Example:

You get something like this

```
array:3 [
  "query" => "select * from `table` where `table`.`id` = ?"
  "bindings" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 1
  ]
  "time" => 0.5
]
```

And replacing the value of bindings in the query you could run the output directly to your database to see if the query is correct

```
Select * from `table` where `table`.`id` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [1] => Array
            (
                [query] => select IF(LOCATE(" ",pro_title,POSITION("can" IN pro_title))"0",SUBSTR(pro_title,POSITION("can" IN pro_title),LOCATE(" ",pro_title,POSITION("can" IN pro_title)) - POSITION("can" IN pro_title) ) , "aaa")  as keyword, `mc_name`, `pro_title` from `nm_product` inner join `nm_maincategory` on `mc_id` = `pro_mc_id` where LOWER(pro_title) like ? or LOWER(pro_title) like ?
                [bindings] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => "% can%"
                        [1] => "can%"
                    )

                [time] => 0.52
            )
```

I replaced the variables and placed the query in phpmyadmin and i got this results

[Display Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoZRy.png)

Comment: store the result in a variable `$foo = DB::table('nm_product')->select(...` then  print this using `dd($foo->toArray())`

Comment: `Fatal Error : Call to a member function toArray() on array`

Comment: try run just `$foo = DB::table('nm_product')->get();` `dd($foo->toArray());`

Comment: `I got the Same Error`

Comment: `$foo = DB::table('nm_product')->get(); dd($foo);` Maybe you're using another database with an empty table check u `.env` file

Comment: if i remove the toArray i got  the arrays result of query `DB::table('nm_product')->get()`, i'm using the right database

Comment: ok, run `$foo = DB::table('nm_product')->select(...`; `dd($foo);` What do you get?

Comment: i got empty result []